# awk solution for pattern matching and allowing one ambiguity/mismatch

Tags: regex, awk, grep

I would like to count the number of strings in a document.

If input is:

```
GGTGGTGGTAT
GGTAGTGGTAT
GGTGGTGGTAT
GGTAATGGTAT
```

And I search for GGTGGTGGT I would like to find 3 matches.  Allowing for one ambiguity.

Using egrep it would look something like this and have an output of 3.

```
 egrep -c "GGTGGTGGT|.GTGGTGGT|G.TGGTGGT|GG.GGTGGT|GGT.GTGGT|GGTG.TGGT|GGTGG.GGT|GGTGGT.GT|GGTGGTG.T|GGTGGTGG." input
```

Comment: what's the logic behind this?

Comment: Allowing for one SNP when searching DNA sequence.

Comment: Use [`regex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) from Python (not the default `re`)? There is no simple solution in ERE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a way to generate that regex with bash:

```
$ patt=(GGTGGTGGT)
$ for ((i=0; i<${#patt[0]}; i++)); do 
    patt+=( "${patt[0]:0:i}.${patt[0]:i+1}" )
  done
$ regex=$(IFS='|'; echo "${patt[*]}")
$ echo "$regex"
GGTGGTGGT|.GTGGTGGT|G.TGGTGGT|GG.GGTGGT|GGT.GTGGT|GGTG.TGGT|GGTGG.GGT|GGTGGT.GT|GGTGGTG.T|GGTGGTGG.
```

and then:

```
awk -v regex="$regex" '$0 ~ regex' file
```

Or with awk only:

```
awk -v srch=GGTGGTGGT '
    BEGIN {
        regex = srch
        for (i=1; i<=length(srch); i++) 
            regex = regex "|" substr(srch,1,i-1) "." substr(srch, i+1)
    }
    $0 ~ regex
' << END
GGTGGTGGTAT
GGTAGTGGTAT
GGTGGTGGTAT
GGTAATGGTAT
END
```

```
GGTGGTGGTAT
GGTAGTGGTAT
GGTGGTGGTAT
```

Comment: Other answers also worked, however was able to achieve the desired result much faster working bash to $regex then  `egrep -c "$regex" file`.

Answer (score 2):

This awk executable script will create the patterns to match on, then test each line to count matches:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { createPatternArray( pattern, a ) }

{
    for( k in a ) { if( $0 ~ k ) { total++; break } }
}

END { print total }

function createPatternArray( pattern, a,       pLen, i ) {
    a[pattern]
    pLen = length( pattern )
    for(i=1; i<=pLen; i++) {
        a[substr(pattern,1,i-1) "." substr(pattern,i+1)]
    }
    # for( k in a ) { print k }
}
```

If it was placed in a file like `awko` (and made executable), then running it on the data is like:

```
awko -v pattern=GGTGGTGGT data
3
```

The `createPatternArray` function makes entries in the array like:

```
.GTGGTGGT
G.TGGTGGT
GG.GGTGGT
GGT.GTGGT
GGTG.TGGT
GGTGG.GGT
GGTGGT.GT
GGTGGTG.T
GGTGGTGG.
GGTGGTGGT
```

For each line, the prefix of the line is tested against the entries in the array.  If there's a match, increment `totals` and then break ( there are multiple matches otherwise ).  At the `END`, print the `total`.

Comment: You don't have to include `a,pLen, i` in the argument list as they aren't passed to the function. Actually as all variables are global in awk you don't even  need an argument list.

Comment: @JID - The variables are scoped locally to the function by naming them in the args list.  In the function, `pattern` is a copy of the global `pattern` and the array `a` is passed by reference.  Because extra parameters aren't passed for `pLen` and `i`, they are merely local, null initialized variables.  It would certainly work to not pass args and use them as globals but I chose not to here.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way using (G)awk and the gensub function

```
awk -va="GGTGGTGGT" '
        {for(i=1;i<=length(a);i++)if($0~gensub(/./,".",i,a)){print;next}}' file
```

---

#### Output

```
GGTGGTGGTAT
GGTAGTGGTAT
GGTGGTGGTAT
```

---

#### How it works

```
-va="GGTGGTGGT"
```

Sets the variable a to the value enclosed in the quotes(whatever you want)

```
{for(i=1;i<=length(a);i++)
```

Creates a loop from 1 to the length of the variable a.The length is the number of character inside the string.

```
if($0~gensub(/./,".",i,a))
```

I'll explain the `gensub` first.
The first two args swap `.`(any character) with a literal `.`. The 3rd argument is the occurrence of the match from argument 1. As we are searching for a single character, then this will just move through the string replacing each character with a `.`. The final arg is the string to edit and `a` is used. `gensub` also returns the string instead of editing the original.

```
$0~
```

Means the whole line contains whatever follows the `~`

These are both contained in an if which when both evaluated will result in

```
$0~.GTGGTGGT
$0~G.TGGTGGT
$0~GG.GGTGGT
$0~GGT.GTGGT
$0~GGTG.TGGT
$0~GGTGG.GGT
$0~GGTGGT.GT
$0~GGTGGTG.T
$0~GGTGGTGG.
```

'

```
{print;next}
```

If any of those match then the line is print and all further instructions are skipped and the next line is processed.

---

#### Resources

https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html

Answer (score 1):

The necessary awk pattern is the same as your egrep solution:

```
awk '/GGTGGTGGT|.GTGGTGGT|G.TGGTGGT|GG.GGTGGT|GGT.GTGGT|GGTG.TGGT|GGTGG.GGT|GGTGGT.GT|GGTGGTG.T|GGTGGTGG./{print $0}' input
```

Comment: Looking for a solution to input just search string "GGTGGTGGT" and awk handles the rest. Possibly creating the drawn out search string including the "." and then performing the search.

Comment: You might consider clarifying your question in that case.

Answer (score 0):

What you really want is `agrep` which stands for approximate grep.  It works incredibly well and is sometimes even faster than regular grep.

You can find the original [here](ftp://ftp.cs.arizona.edu/agrep/).
Installing is as simple as downloading the tar ball, running `tar -xf <file>`, navigating inside the resulting folder, and running `make`

Or the current (and possibly more bloated) version [here](https://github.com/Wikinaut/agrep)

In your case you would simply:

```
agrep -1 GGTGGTGGT <file>
```

The `-#` is the number of mismatches you would like to allow.  The original version supports up to 8 mismatches.

It is important to note that agrep consideres a 'mismatch' to be either an insertion, deletion, or substitution.  So matches with one fewer or one extra character than the pattern string are considered, while all of the other answers here **require the match to have the same number of characters**.